# Convergence of integral formula for Fourier inversion (and Hilbert transform) for integrable piecewise-smooth functions

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, signal-processing

Let $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a **bounded $L^1$ function that is piecewise-smooth** (with the boundaries of the pieces having no accumulation points), but not necessarily continuous. Define the Fourier transform $\hat{f} \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ of $f$ by
$$ \hat{f}(\xi) \ = \ \int_\mathbb{R} f(t) e^{-2\pi i \xi t} \, dt $$
and write $\hat{f}(\xi)=A_\xi e^{i\phi_\xi}\,$ where $A_\xi \geq 0$ and $\phi_\xi \in (-\pi,\pi]$.

> > Is it the case that for almost all $t \in \mathbb{R}$, the limit
> >     \begin{align*}
> > \mathring{f}(t) :=& \lim_{R \to \infty} \int_0^R \mathrm{Im} \Big(\hat{f}(\xi) e^{2\pi i \xi t} \Big) \, d\xi \\
> > =& \lim_{R \to \infty} \int_0^R A_\xi\sin(2\pi\xi t + \phi_\xi) \, d\xi
> > \end{align*}
> >     exists and is finite? (And if so, then is the Hilbert transform of $f$ equal to $2\mathring{f}$?)

Now I have read in a few places that for every $t \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$ \lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{-R}^R \hat{f}(\xi) e^{2\pi i \xi t} \, d\xi \ = \ \tfrac{1}{2}\Big(\lim_{s \to t+} f(s) + \lim_{s \to t-}f(s)\Big). $$

Hence my question is equivalent to the following: For almost all $t$, **can one let the lower and upper boundaries of the above integral tend to $\infty$ independently?**

To see the equivalence: Note that $A_{-\xi}=A_\xi\,$ and if $A_\xi \neq 0$ then $\,\phi_{-\xi}=-\phi_\xi$ (mod $2\pi$). Hence, for all $R_1,R_2>0$,
$$ \int_{-R_1}^{R_2} \hat{f}(\xi) e^{2\pi i \xi t} \, d\xi \ = \ \left( \int_0^{R_1} + \int_0^{R_2} \right) A_\xi\cos(2\pi\xi t + \phi_\xi) \, d\xi \ + \ i\int_{R_1}^{R_2} A_\xi\sin(2\pi\xi t + \phi_\xi) \, d\xi. $$

---

**PS:** If the answer to my question is not necessarily *yes* in general, then I am also very interested in whether it becomes *yes* when we restrict to the set of functions $f$ that are **smooth on a compact interval and vanish everywhere else**.

Comment: Since this question has had no answers (even after a 300-point bounty), I have now posted it at MathOverflow, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/293239/convergence-of-integral-formula-for-fourier-inversion-and-hilbert-transform-fo